# LLVM IR: Get AllocaInst from CreateLoad

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm using the LLVM IR C++ API to generate IR for my compiler. My question boils down to:

> From a `CreateLoad` instruction, can I get the `AllocaInst*` it was loaded from so I can store the result of arithmetic instructions in that `AllocaInst*` without needing to retrieve it from a `namedValues` table?

### Background

My semantic analyzer and IR generator both implement the visitor pattern where visitor method is `accept`. Below, the calls to `accept` are for the IR generator and translate to a call to `llvm::Value* ASTCodegenner::codegen(<subclass of AST>)`.

I've successfully implemented unary instructions so that my compiler can compile things like:

```cpp
int a = 1;
int b = 3 + ++a; // b = 5, a = 2
```

Which translates roughly to (modified for brevity):

```
%a = alloca i32
%b = alloca i32
store i32 1, i32* %a                // store 1 in %a
%a1 = load i32, i32* %a             // load value from %a
%inctmp = add nsw i32 %a1, 1        // add 1 (unary increment, a + 1)
store i32 %inctmp, i32* %a          // store in %a (a = a + 1)
%addtmp = add nsw i32 3, %inctmp    // use incremented value (prefix unary operator, ++a)
store i32 %addtmp, i32* %b          // store result of 3 + ++a in %b
```

The above is also equivalent to clang's IR representation of the same code in `C`.

### Problem

Unary expressions are parsed into a `UnaryExprAST` which receives an `operand` property of `AST` (base class for all AST nodes). My reasoning for this is statements like `++1` should be valid in syntactic analysis but not semantic analysis (`UnaryExprAST.operand` should be able to store `VariableAST`, `NumberAST`, etc.).

The solution I have now is an ugly one involving a `dynamic_cast` from `AST` up to `VariableAST` so I can retrieve its `AllocaInst*` from the `namedValues` table. Hence my curiosity if there was a way to retrieve

```cpp
llvm::Value* ASTCodegenner::codegen(UnaryExprAST* ast) 
{
    // codegen operand. if it's a VariableAST, this returns a load instruction
    // (see below for acutal method)
    llvm::Value* target = ast->operand->accept(*this);

    // retrieve AllocaInst* from namedValues table
    std::unique_ptr<VariableAST> operand = std::unique_ptr<VariableAST>(dynamic_cast<VariableAST*>(ast->operand->clone()));
    llvm::AllocaInst* targetAlloca = namedValues[operand->id];
    
    // this method just returns the result of the unary operation, e.g. 
    // target+1 or target-1, depending on the unary operator
    llvm::Value* res = applyUnaryOperation(target, ast->op);
    // store incremented value
    builder->CreateStore(res, targetAlloca);
    // if prefix unary, return inc/dec value; otherwise, return original value 
    // before inc/dec
    return ast->isPrefix() ? res : target;
}
```

```cpp
llvm::Value* ASTCodegenner::codegen(VariableAST* ast) 
{
    llvm::AllocaInst* val = namedValues[ast->id];
    return builder->CreateLoad(val->getAllocatedType(), val, ast->id);
}
```

I thought about `builder->CreateStore(res, target);` instead of `builder->CreateStore(res, targetAlloca);` but that would violate SSA as `target` is assigned the load operation.

### Possible Solution: #1

A `VariableAST` has a `ctx` property which is a member of an enum:

```
enum class VarCtx
{
    eReference, // referencing a variable (3 * a * 20)
    eStore, // storing new value in a variable (a = ...)
    eAlloc, // allocating a vairable (int a = ...) 
    eParam, // function parameter (func add(int a, int b))
};
```

During my semantic analysis phase (or even the constructor of `UnaryExprAST`), I could `dynamic_cast` the `UnaryExprAST.operand` to `VariableAST`, check for `null`, and then fill the `ctx` with `VarCtx::eStore`. I could then modify the IR generation of `VariableAST` to return the `AllocaInst*` if its `ctx` is `VarCtx::eStore`.

### Possible Solution: #2

Cast the result  of IR generation on the operand (`Value*`) up to `LoadInst`.

```
llvm::LoadInst* target = static_cast<llvm::LoadInst*>(ast->operand->accept(*this));
llvm::Value* targetAlloca = target->getPointerOperand();
```

This works fine and should be OK with a cast from `Value*` to `LoadInst*` as unary operations should only be done on something that needs to be loaded with `CreateLoad` anyways (correct me if I'm wrong).

### Possible Solution: #3

Leave the `dynamic_cast` in IR generation stage and completely rely on my semantic analyzer to let the right values through. I'm not entirely thrilled with that solution as what if I want to be able to define a unary operation for something other than a variable? It seems like a hacky solution that I will have to fix later.

Maybe I'm going about the IR generation completely wrong? Or maybe it's an XY problem and there's something wrong with my class architecture? I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From a CreateLoad instruction, can I get the AllocaInst* it was loaded from so I can store the result of arithmetic instructions in that AllocaInst* without needing to retrieve it from a namedValues table?

`IRBuilder::CreateLoad()` always returns a `LoadInst *` which has a `getPointerOperand()` method that will return the same `Value *` that you created the load with, whether it's an alloca or not. If you're loading something simple like a cast of an alloca, you could use `V->stripPointerCasts()` (note that there is a family of ~8 strip... functions, pick the right one for your purpose). If the load was created as loading something other than an alloca, then no, the load doesn't know how to find which underlying alloca it's really loading, in general that requires solving pointer analysis (aka. alias analysis) which is a very hard problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you would recommend my second solution? I didn't know about `stipPointerCasts()`, I'll definitely have to look into that some more. I guess the safety of this operation (getting alloca from load) is determined by how well my semantic analyzer catches malformed expressions.

Comment: LLVM has its own family of safe casting primitives. Use `isa<Thing>(ptr)` to check or `Thing *thing = dyn_cast<Thing>(ptr);` to cast or else get nullptr. See https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates